# Are there large format (inkjet) printers with affordable ink options?

Tags: printer

I love that I can get 10,000 impressions in my HP LaserJet printer using a $20 toner cartridge.

I would like to purchase a large format printer (it may be used, it may be new) but my biggest concern is the price of the ink.

I'm strongly inclined to base my printer purchase decision solely (more or less) on the cost of the ink.  Are there any large format printers specifically designed to provide low cost printing (i.e. inexpensive ink)?

Comment: What size specifically do you mean by "large format" ? 13"x19"?

Comment: Between 36” and 48”

Comment: Many printers of that size are built for commercial use, they often have refillable ink tanks and are very low cost compared to consumer inkjet cartridges. Nothing will help ink be as cheap as toner though, so expect to pay *a lot* more per page for any inkjet.

Comment: Also, be aware that some printers have contracts *forcing* the purchaser to also purchase the OEM ink on a regular basis. Failure to buy that company's ink will cause the printer to shut down.